# Cross browser tool is having slowness issue

Tags: automated-tests, browser-automation, testcomplete

I am using test complete as a automation development tool and I need to execute the code in the cross browser tool (CBT).
I am experiencing a significant slowness in CBT execution. All tests are failing. 
Appreciate that you can help me to resolve this issue.

Regards,
Senani.

Comment: All the things are broken and slow doesn't narrow it down. Have a look at [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Typically the log files give a good idea of what caused the failure in your test.  I have noticed that sometimes delays need to be added to the tests in order to get them to complete without error, but once again that is what my log files said.  This link may also help. https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/app-testing/web/general/cross-browser/about.html